# IPython (Jupyter) MathJaX preamble

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, mathjax, pandoc

### Question

How can I setup a MathJax "preamble" for use in IPython (or Jupyter) notebooks for repeated use in a way that is convenient for others to read my documents (on http://nbviewer.org) and that works for LaTeX/PDF  generation?

### Background

I would like to use IPython (now Jupyter) notebooks for documents that I later convert to PDF via LaTeX (using `ipython nbconvert`).  The problem is how to include a bunch of macro definitions that I use in almost every document.  Something like:

```
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\vec{#1}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}
```

etc.  As far as the notebooks is concerned, one unsatisfactory solution is to simply include these in a markdown cell at the top of the notebook, embeded between two dollar signs `$$` so it is interpreted as math.  If this is done after some introductory text, then it does not even affect the output.

The problem is that, when converting to LaTeX (for PDF export), these commands are embedded in a math environment in the LaTeX file.  This has several problems:

1. Commands like `\DeclareMathOperator` must come in the LaTeX document preamble.
2. Command definitions are local to the equation and not available later in the document.  (This can be overcome by using `\gdef` or `\global\def` but then one must trick MathJax into recognising these commands with something like `\let\gdef{\def}` which is somehow hidden from LaTeX. Any way I have found of making this work amounts to an ugly hack.)
3. Sometimes commands are already defined in LaTeX and need to have `\renewcommand` (not supported by MathJax, but again can be provided by `\let\renewcommand\newcommand` etc. which seems reasonable to me since MathJax can't have some idea of what preamble might be used for the final LaTeX file).

Probably the solution is to [provide a set of macros to MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros) by adding code like (not sure the equivalent of `\DeclareMathOperator` here...)

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    Macros: {
      vect: ["{\\vec #1}",1],
      abs: ["{\\lvert #1 \\rvert}",1]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

to a `custom.js` file and then providing a LaTeX package for inclusion when converting to PDF.  The problem I have with this approach is: *How to distribute the `custom.js` file and LaTeX style file for others (collaborators and viewers) to use?*

1. I want collaborators to be able to edit and read my documents without having to install custom extensions in their global configuration.  To be specifiec, I am fine with requiring them to run a command like `python setup.py configure` once they download/checkout my code which does *local* modifications to the project like populating `ipython_notebook_config.py` files in all directories containing notebooks, but am not happy installing extensions, or modifying their personal global `custom.js` file.

   My stumbling block here is that I don't know how to add contributions from a local `custom.js` file to the notebook chain, and suspect that this might violate a security policy.

   The best solution would not require any action on my collaborator's part.
2. I want my notebooks to work on http://nbviewer.org, and for people to be able to download the notebook and produce a PDF.  (I *think* this rules out the possibility of using `custom.js` hacks and a distributed `*.sty` file, but am not certain.)
3. I would prefer to be able to simply start a new notebook and then start writing without having to insert a bunch of boilerplate code at the start of each notebook, though would be amenable to having a simple way of automating this process using an notebook extension or some hooks in `python_notebook_config.py`.

### References

The following posts address some of these issues, but fall short on most fronts:

- [usepackage and making macros in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028342)
- [Physics bra-ket symbols in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741672) (specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1974190/1088938) notes related difficulties)
- [How do I get MathJax to enable the mhchem extension in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122210)

Discussions about (potential) problems with the [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) production of LaTeX files from IPython notebooks:

- [Getting some problems with pandoc and mathjax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205426)
- [\newcommand environment when convert from markdown to pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129840)
- [Pandoc IPython notebook loses some Mathjax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464819)

General discussion of math in notebooks:

- [How to write LaTeX in IPython Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208286)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve some of your problems, but not all.

First, the stumbling block.  I believe (though I might be wrong) that nbviewer doesn't look at anything but the notebook itself.  For example, I don't see how it could run an `ipython_notebook_config.py` [stored alongside your notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068671/1194883).  So that rules out that line of thought, meaning that I think you'll have to bite the bullet and add boilerplate to every notebook.  But you might at least be able to minimize the boilerplate.  In that vein:

You could maintain your `custom.js` (probably under a more descriptive name) on github or whatever, and then add one line of boilerplate to all your notebooks to load that script from the URL.  You would still need boilerplate, but it would be a lot shorter.

Once you have executed the code cell containing the javascript, it is saved in the notebook, which means that it will automatically happen the next time the browser loads it, even before the code cell is executed.  So unless nbviewer prevents the javascript's execution, it *should* work just fine.  This would also make things work nicely for collaborators, since they wouldn't have to download additional files.

As for your own style file, I suspect that anyone sophisticated enough to install ipython and latex, download your notebook, and run `nbconvert` on it would also be sophisticated enough to download the `.sty` file.  Anyway, I don't see any way around the need to do that...

Comment: Having a central ``custom.js`` file on the web is not a bad idea, as long as there is also a way to use a local version if it exists (when working on a plane for example).  The question is: where can I include the boilerplate so that it effects the MathJax configuration early enough?  By the first cell of the notebook it appears to be too late, which means I must change a template or something, and my collaborators will not have this template etc.

Comment: My basic test of inserting your sample in a `%%javascript` cell works (if I change to `type="text/Javascript"`).  You have to execute it the first time you put it in, save the notebook, and then refresh the page.  But once this is done, it seems to be saved in the notebook, so in the future you (and your collaborators, or nbviewers) won't need to re-evaluate.  Admittedly, I haven't done the full include-from-remote-URL test.  But I'm not very good with javascript...

Comment: I gisted my basic test, and you can view it [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/moble/4182db185b6cb6a3b1fe).  (I changed `abs` to `abst`, just to make sure it was using the one I defined, instead of amsmath.)  That works, which is encouraging.  But I can't seem to get an equivalent thing working with `<script scr="http://..."></script>`.  But maybe I'm being dumb about something.

Comment: Okay, this seems to work when I view the notebook on nbviewer, or convert the notebook to HTML, but does not work when I serve it live as an IPython notebook.  I do not understand why, but suspect it has something to do with the ``delayStartupUntil=configured`` flag working in the HTML page, but not in the notebook...