# How to write LaTeX in jupyter (not just equations)

Tags: latex, jupyter

Is it possible to write LaTeX in jupyter? It seems that `IPython.display.Latex` supports only a subset of LaTeX equations. In particular I would like to use `\tabular` and others LaTeX commands (`HTML` is not an option).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435997/ipython-jupyter-mathjax-preamble and http://stackoverflow.com/a/16660611/4573247. Comment to the 2nd linked answer, _"in Jupyter, it doesn't work in a markdown cell but it does work in a code cell."_

Comment: `%%latex` only works for equations.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the latex_envs extension in https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions (install from this repo, it is the most recent version -- follow the instructions in the README). Some documentation here https://rawgit.com/jfbercher/latex_envs/master/doc/latex_env_doc.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried this in Jupyter Lab. Mark a cell as "raw". Then:

```
   %%latex

  \bf{This is a test} \\
 It allows latex $\alpha=\beta$ and test:

 \begin{equation}
 \alpha = \beta
 \end{equation}
 % this is a latex comment
```

Then File -> Export Notebook as -> PDF